# Copy multiple cells, not side by side, to cells that are side by side

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

Got this code:

```vb
Sub LoopAllFilesAndCopyPasteKIT()
    
    Dim MyObj As Object
    Dim MySource As Object
    Dim file As Variant
    
    Dim wbThis                  As Workbook     'Denne fila
    Dim wbTarget                As Workbook     'Filer å kopiere data fra
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    
    Dim vDB As Variant
    
    Set wbThis = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sht1 = wbThis.Sheets("Ark1")
    
    Folder = "H:\Mine dokumenter\Nedlastinger\Rapporter\"
    Fname = Dir(Folder)
    
    While (Fname <> "")
    
        Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Folder & Fname)
      
        vDB = wbTarget.Sheets(1).Range("A3:D3")
    
        sht1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
    
        Fname = Dir
    
        'Lukke rapportfilen
        wbTarget.Close
    Wend
    
End Sub
```

The code opens all files in folder and copies cells to a "masterWb", placing data in next empty row.
Target range is set to "A3:D3" (cells side by side).

I want to copy cells B3, G3, B7 and R7.

I tried:

```
vDB = wbTarget.Sheets(1).Range("B3,G3,B7,R7")
```

It gives me an error in the below paste-code.

Comment: When you use a discontinuous range and try putting it in an array, VBA only will put its first area... Where do you want copying the range cells? In a continuous range, on the same row?

Comment: You need a function to transform the discontinue range/array (with multiple rows) in a continue array with only one row. I will prepare and post it...

Comment: Copying first excel file's B3,G3,B7,R7 should end up in wbThis, sheet 1, A2,B2,C2,D2 (got headers). Copying next excel file's B3,G3,B7,R7 should end up in A3,B3,C3,D3 (next row) and so on... Appreciate you helping out, as I see my challenge just got even harder (not written any vba using arrays either)... :-)

Comment: Please check the function I was talking about above and send some feedback. I posted an answer.

Comment: If you copied the function immediately after I posted it, please copy the updated version. I changed only a code line: `arr1 = Range(arr(i)).Value` with `arr1 = rng.Parent.Range(arr(i)).Value`. I created the function working on active sheet, but if the range will belong to another worksheet, it needs to reference the sheet where the range belongs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next function, please. It will transform the discontinuous range in a continue 1D array:

```
Function testUnionDiscontinuousRangeArray(rng As Range, sep As String) As Variant
  Dim arr As Variant, arrF As Variant, arr1 As Variant
  Dim temp As String, i As Long, j As Long
  
   arr = Split(rng.Address, ",")

   For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
    arr1 = rng.Parent.Range(arr(i)).Value
    If IsArray(arr1) Then
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr1)
           temp = temp & Join(Application.Index(arr1, j, 0), sep) & sep
        Next
    Else
        temp = temp & arr1 & sep
    End If
   Next
   temp = left(temp, Len(temp) - 1)
   testUnionDiscontinuousRangeArray = Split(temp, sep)
End Function
```

You can firstly test it in this way:

```
Sub testUnionDiscRange()
  Dim rng As Range, arr1Row As Variant
  Set rng = Range("B3,G3:I3,B7,R7") 'it works on active worksheet
  arr1Row = testUnionDiscontinuousRangeArray(rng, "|")
  Debug.Print Join(arr1Row, "|")
End Sub
```

It will return all the array values separated by "|".

You can use it in your code, in this way:

1. Copy the above function in the same module with your main code.
2. Replace:

```
vDB = wbTarget.Sheets(1).Range("A3:D3")
   sht1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vD
```

with:

```
Dim rngvDB as range
 Set rngvDB = wbTarget.Sheets(1).Range("B3,G3,B7,R7")
 vDB = testUnionDiscontinuousRangeArray(rngvDB, "|")
  ' then use your way of copying the array, but adapted for 1D array type:
 sht1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(1, UBound(vDB) + 1) = vDB
```

**Edited**:

To calculate the real last empty row, in case of empty values in some pasted cells value, please use the next function:

```
Function LastEmptyR(sh As Worksheet, ColNo As Long) As Long
   Dim lastR As Long, i As Long
   For i = 1 To ColNo
       If sh.cells(rows.count, i).End(xlUp).row > lastR Then
            lastR = sh.cells(rows.count, i).End(xlUp).row
       End If
   Next i
   LastEmptyR = lastR + 1
End Function
```

It can be tested in this simple way:

```
Sub testLastEmptyR()
  Debug.Print LastEmptyR(ActiveSheet, 5) '5 = number of columns to be used
End Sub
```

And you will use it as `sht1.Range("A" & LastEmptyR).Resize(1, UBound(vDB) + 1) = vDB`

Comment: Quite fantastic! Thanks a lot! :-) However, maybe one bug: VBA is not pasting the last cell (R7). If I add another cell to the copy-bit ("B3,G3,B7,R7,K9"), then R7 is included - but not K9. What could that be? And another one that just occured to me: If B3 is empty in one of the workbooks copying from, then copy/paste is ok - but when next workbook is pasted it overwrites this row. Got 250 workbooks I want to copy from, and I'm not sure yet if this example may appear: But if, could it be taken into account in any way?

Comment: @kit99: Corrected the above code for the first issue. I missed something obvious for the line where the paste range is resized. Being a 1D array, its `Ubound` starts from zero. I added 1 (`...Resize(1, UBound(vDB) + 1) = vDB`). About the second issue, I am not sure I understood it correctly...  If yes, if empty cells my occur in one column, for such a situation I would suggest you to calculate the last row for all the columns and choose the maximum. I mean, you must calculate it through an iteration. Now I am busy, but I will create a function able to return the appropriate last empty row...

Comment: [FaneDuru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2233308/faneduru): The correction worked fine. And I've taken a closer look at mye copy-from-files, and there should be data in the first cell in all of them. When vba is checking for last row in pasting data, column A should hold data for all of them, leaving no chance for pasting data on top of rows where column A is blank. Thanks a lot again for helping out! :)

Comment: @kit99 I, anyhow, posted the function able to calculate the real empty row, if in the future such a situation may occur. The code would take some micro seconds... You may use it, or not, of course.

Comment: [FaneDuru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2233308/faneduru), you're a genious! :) By trying the vba out on real data, I've hit another snag. It turns out that several of the cells I'm trying to copy data from is merged (no, I did not build this...). Copying B3 when A3:B3 is merged into B3, and pasting this in to 1 cell in wsThis is not within this code to do. But I'm not expecting you to solve this too (if it even can be solved). You've already given me more than enough help!

Comment: [FaneDuru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2233308/faneduru) never mind my last comment. I've solved the merged-problem! Have i nice day! :-)

Comment: @kit99 You could do unmerge in the code. Not so easy if the merged cell value is not of the top left cell and you do not that... If you know that only A:B will be merged, it would be simple. But, glad you could handle it...

Comment: [FaneDuru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2233308/faneduru), terrible sorry to bother you again... Got another one that my head cant get around: Your split-functions uses comma (",") to separate data. But some of the cells I'm copying from holds text where comma is used. When pasting these cells I'm getting a column split for each comma used in the text. Any workaround?

Comment: @kit99: Always should be a workaround... Let us use a character not very probably to be find in your range. "|" for instance... I will adapt the function to use `sep` inside the code and change it according to the need. This time you can try using "|" as I suggested, I think. I will adapt it in a minute... I adapted all code parts. The function itself and the way of calling. In testing environment and on your code, too. If something wrong, doing it fast, please explain where is the problem...

Comment: [FaneDuru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2233308/faneduru), have tried to replace "," in function with "|", but cant get it to work. I'm out of my league here, but it seems to me that Target Range using "," between list of cells to copy makes changing the function problematic...? If function is changed to "|" i assume Target Range must do the same, and thats not a legal vba option?

Comment: @kit99: What to replace? I already adapted the function to accept any separator (as parameter). I said about functon adaptation... You must only copy the updated function and call it adding the separator parameter: `vDB = testUnionDiscontinuousRangeArray(rngvDB, "|")`. The second parameter is the separator. If your data to be processed will also contain it, you can change it with something exotic. Some Greek letters or other symbols...  But if you want to adapt the function by yourself (to learn) you can change any "," whith your simbol, but except the one from: `arr = Split(rng.Address, ",")`

Comment: The one from `arr = Split(rng.Address, ",")` splits the range address, where the separator is comma. Only the rest of code it is used to process all the discontinuous range areas...